# Find the number of water molecules "embedded" in sucrose

Tags: biochemistry, stoichiometry, carbohydrates

Recently I got a question as follows:

> How many molecules of water are joined with 12 atoms of carbon in a molecule of sucrose ?
>
> (A) 12
>
> (B) 11
>
> (C) 6
>
> (D) 10

I am unable to understand the question.
What actually is the question ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Sucrose is a [carbohydrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbohydrate).  This means that stoichiometrically, it can be regarded as adding water ($\ce{H2O}$) to elemental carbon $\ce{C}$.
- The formula of sucrose is $\ce{C12H22O11}$.
- Another way to write this formula is $\ce{C12(H2O)11}$.
- Thus, sucrose can be regarded (stoichiometrically, but not structurally) as eleven waters plus twelve elemental carbons.  Therefore ***the correct answer is (b)***.
- The question is not well-worded, and would be better stated as "*How many water molecules are required to join with the 12 carbon atoms in sucrose to give the correct empirical formula for sucrose?*".
- In the comments Ivan Neretin offers an even better variant, which I will re-word as "*How many water molecules could extremely powerful dehydrating agents such as $\ce{H2SO4}$ or $\ce{SO3}$ extract from sucrose, if we assume the only non-water product is pure carbon?*".

Comment: That would be not quite good either. Water molecules don't just up and join carbon atoms on their own. I don't know how to salvage this question. Maybe, _"How many water molecules can be snatched from sucrose by $\ce{H2SO4}$, if the product is assumed to be pure carbon."_

Comment: Thanks & good point.   I added your idea to the answer.  Perhaps a better word than "join" is "embed", which may be suitably ambiguous for this somewhat vague question.

Comment: @Curt F I was quite thinking about how many water molecules can be joined with sucrose molecule with the help of hydrogen bond. But because there was no mention of Hydrogen bond  so I didn't knew what actually it means.

Comment: It really is a misleading 'trick' question. I just does not help to understand the structure of sucrose, in fact quite the opposite.

Comment: It's not really a trick question.  It requires stoichiometric thinking (all they had in the old days) instead of structural thinking, though.